# Front Blank Webpage

Tags: views, dependency-injection

Hi I am working on moving my website from local to development, but get this error:

**Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Class "Drupal\entity\QueryAccess\ViewsQueryAlter" does not exist." at /var/www/website/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php line 24**

When I try to render the front page it is blank, but when I target internal webpages, some of them work. I tried googling what this error meant to no avail. Any tips on how to debug this error would be of great help! Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the same database? And did you enable the same plugins?

Comment: I found out that I did not enable the same plugins, I had to use `composer install` to install the missing php dependencies! Thank you

Comment: Glad things worked out! I'll go ahead and add this as an answer so the question has an answer. Let me know if there's anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install and enable the same plugins from your local as on your development if you are using things dependent on them. If your site was built with composer make sure you run 'composer update' or 'composer install'.